# VBA: Not able to get UserPicture to fill an excel chart shape using a cell's text value

Tags: vba, excel

Help! We are not VBA experienced beyond simple Excel macros. We're trying to fill auto generated chart shapes with a cell's reference to a file path. We can only get it to work by manually including the file path in the code.

This Works:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    chrt.SetSourceData Source:=Union(.Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, LastColumn)), _
                                     .Range(.Cells(a, 2), .Cells(a, LastColumn)))

    chrt.HasTitle = True '<~~ Add the Chart Title
    chrt.ChartTitle.Text = .Cells(a, 1).Value '<~~ Set the text
    chrt.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 64, 25, 184, 116).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture "C:\Users\user\Pictures\map of Wilmington.png"
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
```

We would like THIS to work by referencing a cell on another sheet or whatever can accomplish it:

```
.UserPicture (Range("Sheet3!B2"))
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
```

[Same shape pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPwL5.jpg)

What we're trying to get are different pictures in the shape based on the file path's entered on a different sheets referenced cells.

Entire code:

```
Sub AutoCreateCharts()
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim chrt As Chart

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3000").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

For a = 2 To LastRow
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Set chrt = Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
chrt.ChartType = xlDoughnut
chrt.HasLegend = True '<~~ Add the legend
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    chrt.SetSourceData Source:=Union(.Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, LastColumn)), _
                                     .Range(.Cells(a, 2), .Cells(a, LastColumn)))

    chrt.HasTitle = True '<~~ Add the Chart Title
    chrt.ChartTitle.Text = .Cells(a, 1).Value '<~~ Set the text
    chrt.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 64, 25, 184, 160).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2").Value
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
    End With
End With
chrt.ChartArea.Left = 1
chrt.ChartArea.Top = (a - 2) * chrt.ChartArea.Height
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is "Sheet" the name of your worksheet?  Also in your example #1 you're  setting the value of UserPicture but in #2 you're setting TextureTile.

Comment: Try `.UserPicture Worksheets("Sheet").Range("B2").Value` noting the use of `.Value` as you want to pass a `String` to the `UserPicture` function, not a `Range` object.

Comment: Ashlee - its actually Sheet3. Sorry about the typo.                                               Robin - I'll try that shortly.

Comment: Robin - I get a different error when entering your suggested edit. I get "Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)': Method 'UserPicture' of object 'FillFormat' failed. I've added the whole code in case there is something else missing your expertise would catch that we wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of my computer to test but this should work if your example #1 works:

```
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .UserPicture = worksheets("yourworksheetname").range("b2").Value
    .TextureTile = msoFalse
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I'm getting an error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. The first chart actually generates with a blank shape.